# mySQL PHP WHERE IN returns a table- How do I parse this table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause, where-in

How do I use the data returned by a SQL `WHERE IN(x,y)` statement with PHP?

```
                $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE userid IN ('35','101','45')";

                if ($test_stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sqlquery)) { //Get all data in schedule row
                    $test_stmt->execute(); //Execute the prepared query
                    $test_stmt->store_result(); //Store result
                    $test_stmt->fetch();
                    do something...

                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }

            }
```

The SQL query returns the correct three table rows, I'm just not sure how to access them with PHP.

How do I create an array to store the values the query returns? Or is there a better way to store this data to later be manipulated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to do this is through a loop akin to the following:

```
$results=array();
while($row=$test_stmt->fetch())
{
    $results[]=$row;
}
```

This inserts the row into the results variable, which is an array. At the end of the loop, the array will contain a copy of everything the query returned.

You can also pick and choose what you do with particular columns in the results like this:

```
$results=array();
while($row=$test_stmt->fetch())
{
    $results[]['ID']=$row['ID'];
}
```

This assumes there is a column called "ID" in the results though.

Comment: ok thanks- so I would replace `this->fetch()` with what you put

Comment: @user2415992 I modified the code slightly to use the objects that you had. It should work now if you replace your `fetch()` statement with this directly.

Comment: do I include `(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`? It throws an error that there was an unexpected `(` when I leave it in.

Comment: @user2415992 Goodness me, sorry about that, I had a spare set of `()` from when I copied your objects. Should be good now.

Comment: Hmm... It returns this error `mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in phpfile.php` Is there an object oriented solution to this problem?

Comment: I meant `mysqli` solution ^^

Comment: @user2415992 I haven't ever used mysqli, but if you drop the PDO:: bit, it might work :) I also updated the answer to drop the PDO bits of the code.

Comment: Lol yeah I tried that but it returned a `boolean` value for $row for some reason. I'm trying to find mysqli alternatives to PDO fetch statements but its a pretty limited selection

Answer (score 0):

```
//$test_stmt->store_result(); //not needed
$rows = $test_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //or other fetch mode

print_r($rows);  //$rows is an array of rows you can loop through
```